# Flip transition for desktop browser

Tags: jquery, animation

I just watched a jQuery mobile introductory video featuring the flip transition.

I find it really neat. Is it easy to reproduce the flip effect for desktop browsers without having to use the jQuery mobile library? It is a matter of a few lines of code?

[Note: I'm perfectly fine using jQuery UI.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS3 transitions to animate a flip effect. Here is a demo that you can pull code from: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/.

Be aware that vender prefixes for the `transform` and `transition` properties will be necessary to support multiple browsers (-moz-, -o-, -webkit-). I generally detect which vender prefix to use with [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com).

Here is a list of supported browsers from caniuse.com: http://caniuse.com/#search=transition